# How determine file system path of existing svn repository

Tags: svn

We have an svn server sitting on a virtualised version of ubuntu 10.04. 
Since the developer who set it up is no longer present, how do I go about 
finding out where a given repository lives on the file system?

We do have full access SSh access to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the repository is served by Apache HTTP Server, then check the server's `httpd.conf`. You should look for [SVNPath or SVNParentPath directives](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.basic).

If the repository is served by [`svnserve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html), look for `-r` in its configuration or command line that starts it.